# How to deploy angular app on docker environment

Tags: docker, angular8

I have developed an Angular 8 app. I have pushed the code to the remote repo and it is building successfully and also I cloned the repo and ran the app locally and it is working fine. Now in the dev environment when I am hitting the dev env URL I am not able to see anything. What all settings needs to be changed?
Docker File Code:

```
FROM sit-dtr.abc.com/core/nodebase:1.0.0
USER root
COPY / ./codebase
WORKDIR /codebase
RUN npm install
FROM Nginx:alpine
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemmon off;"]
```

I have provided normal routing in the app.routing.module.ts file like we provide in an angular app.

Also, I have a very simple package.json file. I have not provided any build or anything like that. Can you suggest what changes would be required in all these files to make the app work?

Answer (score 0):

In shortest `docker run -p localhost:8000:4200`. 
I am supposing, that your Angular app is working on port 4200 and with this command you will be able to access the app on localhost:8000.

Here is nice explanation on this [link](https://vsupalov.com/docker-expose-ports/)

Also, you might want to take a look on docker-compose.